# Grails image manipulation

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

i tried to use in my grails project (1.1.1, on Mac OS X) some image manipulation plugins or java libs: imageTools plugin, imageJ, awt libs etc. Everytime i open/take image from path to start the process, **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter** jar opens in finder and eats a lot of ram.

Is it correct behaviour?

update - sample codes:

```
def openFilePath = "/path/to/the/file/testfile.jpg" 
def imageTool = new ImageTool() 
imageTool.load(openFilePath)
```

ImageTool Plugin, but it happens also with imageJ and other java image libs. If i use NetBeans, the ....cli.support.GrailsStarter process has a NetBeans parent. If i start with terminal, bash is a parent of process. It's everytime it gets a file to open, like here:

```
imageTool.load(openFilePath)
```

With imageJ:

```
def o = new Opener() 
def imp = o.openImage(openFilePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

We do image manipulation as well. On Mac OS X computers the Grails app opens as a new window in Finder. This is normal, and should not cause any problems. Also, if you resize your display or plug in additional monitors while the app is running, you'll get native library errors in your stdout, but I've yet to see any issues to the running app from this.